# How to convert FPDM to support special characters when filling a PDF form?

Tags: php, html, forms, pdf, special-characters

I am fairly inexperienced with programming and for the past 2 days I have been trying to figure out how to fix a problem with special characters when filling a PDF form I have prepared. As I am currently in the testing mode, I created a test pdf named **forma.pdf** in Adobe Illustrator, which I then converted to a pdf form using Adobe Acrobat.

**Said .pdf contains the following fields:**

- name
- surname
- city
- email

I then moved to creating the web form which will be used to fill the .pdf file. Here's the html form code:

**fill_pdf.php**

```
<html>
  <form method="POST" action="submit_post.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="surname" /><br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit!" />
  </form>
</html>
```

**submit_post.php**

```
<?php

/***************************
  Sample using a PHP array
****************************/

$jmeno = $_POST['name'];
$prijmeni = $_POST['surname'];
$city = "Prague";
$email = "dump@mail.com";

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

require('fpdm.php');

$fields = array(
    'name'    => $jmeno,
    'surname' => $prijmeni,
    'city'    => $city,
    'email'   => $email
);

$pdf = new FPDM('forma.pdf');
$pdf->Load($fields, false); // second parameter: false if field values are in ISO-8859-1, true if UTF-8
$pdf->Merge();
$pdf->Output();

}

?>
```

As you can see, I am using the [FPDM](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script93.php) script, which is used to fill pre-created .pdf forms. Now, the html form works fine and does fill the .pdf, unless I input special characters, such as "Š, Č, Ř, š, č, ř,..." Many names in my country include these special characters, so I need them to show up in the .pdf once it's generated.

Do you guys have any idea what I am supposed to change in order to make the special characters work?

Thank you very much for replies.

Comment: @derp Thank you for the quick answer. I tried changing the value from _false_ to _true_ and then inserting one of the special characters gives me the following error: http://i.imgur.com/7KEQ0tu.png When I change it back to **false**, it does fill the .pdf file but the characters are all messed up, as said in the previous post. Judging by the error report, it looks like the problem is within the fpdm.php file itself, but I don't really know what I should change.